# No more satisfying instances

Tags: alloy

No examples generated for my alloy model with the error message: 'No more satisfying instances' (see image attached)

I have created the following small model in Alloy:

```
sig System 
{
    subSystem : System
}

// Prevent a subsystem from directly including itself
fact noDirectInclusion
{
    no s : System | s in s.subSystem
}

// Prevent a subsystem from transitivelyincluding itself
fact noTransitiveInclusion
{
    no s : System | s in s.^subSystem
}

pred show {}

run show for 5
```

The fact 'noDirectInclusion' nicely prevents the generation of examples where a subsystem is a subsystem of itself.

I am probably missing something trivial, but When I also use the fact 'noTransitiveInclusion' there are no longer any examples generated with the error message: 'No more satisfying instances' (see image attached)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

Try to make your graph by hand for only 2 `System` sigs ...

You will see that with the constraints you specified in the `System` sig you can only make a cycle ... You force a `System` to have 1 and exactly 1 `subSystem`, i.e. the default for a field is `one`. Therefore, the transitive graph can only be a cycle with a finite set of objects and that invalidates your fact.

Either make `subSystem` a `lone` or `set`.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I missed the default of one reading the docs...